# The perfect matching problem of planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, perfect-matchings, hamiltonian-graphs, planar-graphs

We know that connectivity  is closely related to the Hamiltonian of planar graphs.
The most famous result is the Tutte theorem.

**Theorem (Tutte, 1956).** A 4-connected planar graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.

It's worth noting that this theorem was later extended.
For example:  Thomassen proves one of Plummer's conjectures: **Every 4-connected planar graph is Hamiltonian-connected.**

Anyway, Tutte's theorem follows that **any  4-connected planar graph $G$  has an almost perfect matching, and in the case of even order, $G$ has a perfect matching.**

I have a potentially naive question:

> If we do not use Tutte's theorem, can we prove that any 4 connected planar
> graph has an almost perfect matching? What are the possible directions of proof?

Because of Tutte's strong results, there seem to be fewer ways to determine if a planar graph contains a perfect matching (or people don't pay much attention to it).

I wonder if anyone has ever dealt with this problem.

Comment: Not relevant to your interesting question, but for those who might be wondering, the 1-skeleton of the rhombic dodecahedron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron) is a 3-connected planar graph which is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: @SamHopkins It's also a good way to think about it. To find a class of planar graphs that are not Hamiltonian but have a perfect matching. More general methods of proving that a planar graph contains a perfect matching seem to be rare.

Comment: Well if you're looking for examples of planar graphs that are not Hamiltonian but contain perfect matchings, you can compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinberg%27s_theorem.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks! I'm actually more interested in whether some special theoretical tool has been developed for determining whether a plane graph has a 1 factor. And we might have a Tutte 1-factor theorem for general graphs, although it is not so easy to use. .

Comment: Pfaffian orientations are an example of such a theoretical tool (planar graphs are pfaffian). See for instance http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_III/contents/ICM_Vol_3_47.pdf for a survey.

Comment: You can also look at this paper for references and results on large matchings in planar graphs of large minimum degree https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07812.pdf . The matchings are quite far from perfect matchings though, and only 3-connected planar graphs are studied.

Comment: @LouisEsperet Thank you. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article provides a positive answer to my question. Yes, it is possible to prove that a 4-connected planar graph has a perfect matching or almost perfect matching even without using the Hamiltonian property.

- Biedl, Therese, et al. "Tight bounds on maximal and maximum matchings." Discrete Mathematics 285.1-3 (2004): 7-15.

Here is my selective excerpt (because the authors also did something else in the same article).

**1.**  First, the authors introduce the concept of the **4-block tree**.

> Similar to the 2-block tree, we can define a 4-block tree that
> captures the relationships among the **4-connected components** of a graph
> (Fig. 2). Recall that a graph is 4-connected if removing any three
> arbitrary vertices leaves a connected graph. Assume that a graph is
> 3-connected, but not 4-connected. Then it contains three vertices
> $\{v, w, x\}$ such that removing them from the graph yields at least
> two connected components; we call $\{v, w, x\}$ a separating triplet.
> For each connected component $C$ obtained from removing $\{v, w, x\}$,
> we create a new graph by adding to $C$ the vertices $v, w, x$, as well
> as all their edges incident to another vertex in $C$, and the three
> edges $(v, w),(w, x)$ and $(x, v)$ if they did not exist already.
>
> We iterate this process until all resulting graphs are 4-connected;
> these are the 4-connected components of the graph. The 4-block tree is
> then defined as follows. We create one node for every 4-connected
> component, and one node for every separating triplet, and add an edge
> if and only if the separating triplet was contained in the 4-connected
> component. The resulting graph is again a tree. We denote its number
> of leaves by $\ell_4(G)$, or just $\ell_4$ if the graph is clear from
> the context.
>
> Note that each leaf of the 4-block tree corresponds to some subgraph
> of $G$ that would be 4-connected if we added all edges between the
> vertices of the separating triplet that defined it.

[image]

**2. Main theorem.**

> Nishizeki and Baybars showed that every 3-connected planar graph has a matching of size $\frac{n+4}{3}$ [9]. In this section, we
> strengthen this result by including the number of leaves of the
> 4-block tree in the bound; **in particular we obtain a bound that
> resolves to** $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ **if the graph is
> 4-connected.**

**Theorem 3.** Any 3-connected planar graph $G$ of order $n$ has a matching of size $\min \left\{\frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{2 n+4-\ell_4}{4}\right\}$, where $\ell_4$ is the number of leaves of the 4-block tree of $G$.

Proof. Let $G$ be a 3-connected planar graph of order $n$, and let $M$ be a maximum matching in $G$. By Theorem 2 , there exists a vertex set $T$ in $G$ such that there are exactly $\left|V_{\neg M}\right|=\operatorname{odd}(T)-|T|$ unmatched vertices in $M$. If $|T| \leqslant 2$, then $G-T$ is still connected, i.e., $\left|V_{\neg M}\right| \leqslant \operatorname{odd}(T) \leqslant 1$. But then clearly $|M| \geqslant \frac{n-1}{2}$.

If $|T|=3$, then there can be at most two odd components in $G-T$. If there were three or more components, they would all have to be incident to all vertices of $T$ by 3 -connectivity, and the graph would contain $K_{3,3}$ as a minor. But $G$ is planar, so this is impossible. Since we assumed that there are $\operatorname{odd}(T)-|T|<0$ unmatched vertices, this case is actually impossible.

If $|T| \geqslant 4$, then we greedily add edges between any two non-adjacent vertices of $T$ that lie on the same face of $G$, without destroying the planarity of the graph. Let $G_T$ denote the subgraph of this augmented graph induced by the vertices of $T$ (see Fig. 3). Note that no two components of $G-T$ can be within the same face of $G_T$, because then we would have introduced an edge to split the face between them. Therefore, for every odd component there must be a unique face in $G_T$. This immediately proves $\operatorname{odd}(T) \leqslant 2|T|-4$, but in fact, we can do better and show $2 \operatorname{odd}(T) \leqslant 2|T|-4+\ell_4$.

More precisely, let $f_3$ and $f_{\geqslant 4}$ be the number of faces of $G_T$ of degree 3 and degree at least 4 , respectively. An easy counting argument shows that $f_3+2 f_{\geqslant 4} \leqslant 2|T|-4$. Let $C$ be an odd component, and let $f_C$ be the face of $G_T$ containing $C$. If $f_C$ has degree 3 , then $C$ has only three neighbors in $T$, and these three neighbors form a separating triplet of $G$ (separating $C$ from the rest of $T$, remember that $|T| \geqslant 4$ ). This separating triplet is the ancestor of at least one leaf of the 4-block tree of $G$. So $C$ can be associated with one face of $G_T$ that has degree 3 and one leaf of the 4-block tree. If $f_C$ has a higher degree, then $C$ can be associated with one face of $G_T$ that counts towards $f_{\geqslant 4}$. So $2 \operatorname{odd}(T) \leqslant f_3+\ell_4+2 f_{\geqslant 4} \leqslant 2|T|-4+\ell_4$.
But then $\left|V_{\neg M}\right| \leqslant \frac{2|T|-4+\ell_4}{2}-|T|=\frac{\ell_4-4}{2}$, which implies $\left|V_M\right| \geqslant n-\left|V_{\neg M}\right| \geqslant \frac{2 n+4-\ell_4}{2}$.

[image]